# How to change Button text in ionic2 using Renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am not getting how to change the button text in ionic2 using ElementRef & Renderer2 class.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: `<button #button type="submit" class="form-button" ion-button 
                [disabled]="!form.valid">Change this text</button>`;
})
export class component {
   @ViewChild('button', {read: ElementRef}) 
   private button : ElementRef;

   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){
   }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.button.nativeElement, 'value', 'Cute alligator');
   }
}
```

This `setProperty` only change the value of the button which is as attribute. But I want to change the button text which is now `Change this text` inside button.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It is required to use renderer2?

Comment: you can normally bind property and change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
this.button.nativeElement.innerText = 'your text';
```

Comment: Thanks @vivek-doshi. Its Works.

Comment: Please correct your answer in favor of Nishant Singh

Answer (score 6):

Using Renderer

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.button.nativeElement, 'textContent', 'Your Text')
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer because the question ask 'using renderer2'